# Show logo in navbar when div scrolled out of view using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Dear friends/colleagues,

As I mentioned in one of my previous questions, I'm just learning AngularJS and I have a question.

What I'm trying to accomplish is the following:

I have a big version of logo that is inside a div in body, now, I want to be able to show the small version of the same logo in the navbar, once the big version is scrolled out of view, using AngularJS. I could do this with JQuery and scrollSpy, but the project is AngularJS specific, and I know that Angular can handle this task, it just seems that I can't get a grip of it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have wrote a directive which applies to pageYoffset, but that doesn't apply when page is in mobile view for example, that is why I need help to apply that directive to an element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can write and use a directive for that. in which, you should use the scroll amount, and also `ng-show` on the little logo's `div` with a  minimum value of the scroll amount that's returned by the directive.

i'll try to write the directive for you

```
.directive('dirScrollTop', function($window, $parse) {
    return {
        scope: {
            scroll: '=dirScrollTop'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var windowEl = angular.element($window);
            var handler = function(e) {
                scope.scroll = $window.pageYOffset;
            }
            windowEl.on('scroll', scope.$apply.bind(scope, handler));
            handler();
        }
    };
})
```

and inside html, write this inside the `<div>` or `<img>` or... that contains the logo:

```
<div dir-scroll-top="scrollVariable" ng-show="scrollVariable > someValue">
```

and inside your controller define `$scope.scrollVariable = 0` and `$scope.someValue` and give this second one the pixel amount necessary for scroll that your other `<div>` goes out of view... you should assign it a number like `$scope.someValue=100;`

i also should say, it's better to get that top amount dynamically (specially if your design is responsive and the distance isn't static) using `getBoundingClientRect()` like this in the directive:

```
var someValue = element[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

and check the distance inside the directive, and directly return a boolean value. so it would go like this:

```
var handler = function(e) {
     var someValue = element[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;
     var scrollOffset = $window.pageYOffset;
     scope.scroll = $window.pageYOffset > someValue;
}
```

and the html would go like this:

```
<div dir-scroll-top="scrollVariable" ng-show="scrollVariable">
```

and in controller just define:

```
$scope.scrollVariable = false;
```

**Update:**

so if i'm not wrong, you want to show/hide the two images when window's scroll makes the bigger image go out of the view.

```
logoShow.directive('dirScrollTop', function($window, $parse) {
return {
    scope: {
        scroll: '=dirScrollTop'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var windowEl = angular.element($window);
        var someValue = element[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
        var handler = function(e) {
            var scrollOffset = element[0].scrollTop;
            scope.scroll = scrollOffset > someValue;
        };
        windowEl.on('scroll', scope.$apply.bind(scope, handler));
        handler();
    }
};
});
```

and for html:

```
<div class="logo-big">
  <img src="assets/img/logo_big.png" dir-scroll-top="scrollVariable" class="img-responsive center-block" />
</div>
```

and

```
    <div class="navbar-brand" ng-show="scrollVariable">
      <img src="assets/img/logo_menu.png" />
    </div>
```

controller:

```
logoShow.controller('logoShowCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.scrollVariable = false;
});
```

this will show the logo when the big image is completely out of view(when it's bottom reaches top of the view). if you want it to happen when the bigger image's top reaches the top of view, you should replace `element[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom` with `element[0].getBoundingClientRect().top` inside the directive.

Comment: That would be greatly appreciated, if possible.

Comment: Is it possible to apply the same logic to a div, instead of the pageYOffset?

Comment: if you want to check the amount of an element's scroll (and element that it's `overflow-y` is set to `scroll`) instead of the page's scroll, you can simply use `element[0].scrollTop` inside the handler instead of `$window.pageYOffset`

Comment: you should also put the `dir-scroll-top="scrollVariable"` on that scrolled element, and use the `scrollVariable` inside the other element's `ng-show`

Comment: I'm trying this and I can't seem to get it to work. I know that it's too much to ask, but is there any chance you can complete this code for me, the way it should be, I would greatly appreciate it, please.

Comment: can you give me what you've written in html / controller / directive ?

Comment: E have edited the response below with the controller/directive.

Comment: OK, did exactly as you wrote. Now, the small logo is hidden, but when I scroll and the big logo goes out of view, the small logo doesn't show up. It stays blank and I get the element is not a function error in console.

Comment: ok, try replacing `var someValue = element[0].getBoundingClientRect().top` with a constant number like: `var someValue = 100`. see if it works

Comment: if it works the problem is because inside the handler , every time scroll happens this changes too: `element[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;` so you should put it out of hendler. i'll edit the answer, check it

Comment: Regardless of combinations that I make, still doesn't work. I can see that there is no controller in your code, can that be a problem?

Comment: oh i assumed you have written the controller as you said in your answer. ofcourse it's needed! just write it exactly as you did before

Comment: OK, I did that as well, now, I'm having a different issue. I have multiple controllers in my application, therefore, where do I place this controller, and do I need to do nesting if I want them all to work?

Comment: inside the html that contains this two `<div>`s, there should be an element that you've assigned `ng-app=...` and a `ng-controller=...` that assigns the controller to it . you should define this `$scope.scrollVariable = false;` inside that controller. or if there are many controllers for many pages, just put it in the controller assigned to the page that contains these images...

Comment: OK, I got this to work, "kind of". When big logo is in view and you refresh the page, the small logo is hidden, but, if I scroll down to next section, to make big logo hidden and refresh the page, small logo shows up. It's working, just doesn't want to update in real time. Am I overseeing something?

Comment: it shouldn't work like that, i should see your complete code. and can you create a snippet of it?
also, you can trace it by putting a `console.log(scope.scroll)` inside the directive, at the end of `handler` function, and see if it logs it whenever you scroll... or from devtools

Comment: OK, after I placed the console.log, I get false on initial page load, and when I scroll, past the big logo it still stays false, regardless. If I hit refresh, it changes to true. I will try to create a snippet, just give me a sec.

Comment: ok, see if you can do anything with this. Hope I did it right. https://jsfiddle.net/edineraweb/ave3my4d/2/

Comment: the fiddle doesn't work and gives the error  [$injector:modulerr]. is it exactly the code you're using??

Comment: Is there a way we can transfer this discussion to some other place that is more private, so I can give you an access to a full project, and then we can post a solution here if found?

Comment: you should have received an email.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is what I had written, and it should work, but is it possible, instead of pageYoffset, to apply all this to a specific div id?

```
.directive("scroll", function($window) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
            if (this.pageYOffset >=500) {
                scope.boolChangeClass = true;
                console.log('Scrolled out of view.');
            } else {
                scope.boolChangeClass = false;
                console.log('Logo is in view.');
            }
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
});
```

EDIT:

Here is what I have done, probably wrong:

```
var logoShow = angular.module('myApp.logoShow', []);

logoShow.controller('logoShowCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.scrollVariable = false;
});


logoShow.directive('dirScrollTop', function($window, $parse) {
    return {
        scope: {
            scroll: '=dirScrollTop'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var windowEl = angular.element($window);
            var handler = function(e) {
                var someValue = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                var scrollOffset = element(0).scrollTop;
                scope.scroll = element.getBoundingClientRect() > someValue;
            };
            windowEl.on('scroll', scope.$apply.bind(scope, handler));
            handler();
        }
    };
});
```

EDIT 2

This is the logo I want to show:

```
<div class="navbar-brand">
          <img src="assets/img/logo_menu.png" />
        </div>
```

when this one scrolls out of view:

```
<div class="logo-big">
      <img src="assets/img/logo_big.png" dir-scroll-top="scrollVariable" class="img-responsive center-block" />
    </div>
```

Comment: what about the html code?

do you want to show the little logo when another `div` is scrolled? (instead of the whole page's scroll)